# Use an array of struct dynamically allocated in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, allocation

I'm writing an application using the C language.
I created an new type based on a structure:

```
typedef struct ENTITY
{
    char * field1;
    char * field2;
} entity;
```

Then, I defined a function to dynamically allocate an array of entities:

```
int my_function(entity ** my_array)
{
    count = random_int(1, 10);

    entity * result;
    result = (entity *) calloc(count, sizeof(entity));

    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    {
        (result+i)->field1 = strdup("Blabla in field1");
        (result+i)->field2 = strdup("Blabla in flied2");

        // This line print correctly "Blabla in field1" for each element in the array.
        printf("->{%s}\n", (result+i)->field1);
    }

    *my_array = result;
    return count;
}
```

In my main file, I use this function:

```
entity * my_array;
count = my_function(&my_array);

for(i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
{
    printf("field1 of the element %d: %s\n", i, my_array[i].field1);
}
```

For some reason, this code works when my array is fulfilled by <= 3 elements, from 4 elements in the array I get a segmentation fault error:

```
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
field1 of the element 0: `�fZ$
Segmentation fault
```

I've read a lot about dynamic allocations on here but I can't manage to fix this problem. Any clue?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Shouldn't `result` be an `entity **`?

Comment: Nope, and this basically works fine for me (once I add the missing headers, declare the count variables and replace the omitted `random_int` function with literal `4`). Can you try the same (hardcode `int count = 4`) and see if it still fails? If it does, post the minimal _compilable_ code that still shows the problem

Comment: @user There is nothing wrong in what you are doing(http://ideone.com/V4jgG). Show what `random_int` function is doing. And may be you are not showing what exactly you are doing.

Comment: How did you compile it? What did the compiler complain about? Where is `count` declared?

Comment: I've tried again by defining count manually:
    int count = 4;
Still the same error.
I compiled with GCC:
    gcc main.c -o main

Comment: @user1382094, could post a complete example that reproduces this?

Comment: @hmjd, Unfortunately I couldn't: my code is a piece of a FreeRTOS task, running with the POSIX simulator (and compiled using GCC). Do you think it could the reason of my problem?
I still don't understand with it works with 3 elements, but not 4.

Comment: Have you checked that `calloc` and `strdup` aren't failing and returning `NULL`?  Maybe your simulator is running out of memory somehow?

Comment: Does your simulator allow the use of some sort of debugger? If so have you tried setting a breakpoint after the call to random_int() and checking what is returned? Often in the cases the use of a debugger is very helpful. Or if you don't have access to a debugger perhaps you could sprinkle your code with debug printf()'s to determine what might be going wrong.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, I've checked `calloc` and `strdup`, they aren't returning `NULL`. I've replaced `calloc` by `pvPortMalloc` which is the function that implements memory allocation in FreeRTOS.

Answer (score 1):

You code works after removing the call to random_int() and replacing it with a hard coded amount as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct ENTITY
{
    char * field1;
    char * field2;
} entity;


int my_function(entity ** my_array)
{
    int count = 10;

    entity * result;
    result = (entity *) calloc(count, sizeof(entity));

    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    {
        (result+i)->field1 = strdup("Blabla in field1");
        (result+i)->field2 = strdup("Blabla in flied2");
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    {
        // This line print correctly "Blabla in field1" for each element in the array.
        printf("->{%s}\n", (result+i)->field1);
    }    


    *my_array = result;
    return count;
}



int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int count;
    int i;

    entity * my_array;
    count = my_function(&my_array);

    for(i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    {
        printf("MAIN::field1 of the element %d: %s\n", i, my_array[i].field1);
        printf("MAIN::field2 of the element %d: %s\n", i, my_array[i].field2);
   }

    return( 0 );
}
```

The output of this is:

```
[root@jrn SO]# gcc  array.c
[root@jrn SO]# ./a.out 
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
->{Blabla in field1}
MAIN::field1 of the element 0: Blabla in field1
MAIN::field2 of the element 0: Blabla in flied2
MAIN::field1 of the element 1: Blabla in field1
MAIN::field2 of the element 1: Blabla in flied2
MAIN::field1 of the element 2: Blabla in field1
MAIN::field2 of the element 2: Blabla in flied2
MAIN::field1 of the element 3: Blabla in field1
MAIN::field2 of the element 3: Blabla in flied2
MAIN::field1 of the element 4: Blabla in field1
MAIN::field2 of the element 4: Blabla in flied2
MAIN::field1 of the element 5: Blabla in field1
MAIN::field2 of the element 5: Blabla in flied2
MAIN::field1 of the element 6: Blabla in field1
MAIN::field2 of the element 6: Blabla in flied2
MAIN::field1 of the element 7: Blabla in field1
MAIN::field2 of the element 7: Blabla in flied2
MAIN::field1 of the element 8: Blabla in field1
MAIN::field2 of the element 8: Blabla in flied2
MAIN::field1 of the element 9: Blabla in field1
MAIN::field2 of the element 9: Blabla in flied2
```